# Qcow2 image works with virt-manager, but throws cloud-init error with virt-install

Tags: cloud-init, virt-install

I have `CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-20140929_01.qcow2` image. When i boot it via `virt-manager` gui, it comes up well. No issues..

But i used `virt-install` to bring up the same qcow2 image as,

```
virt-install --name demo-vm --ram 1024 --disk /home/sk/images/vm-s/crap-vms.qcow2,size=8,format=qcow2 --vcpus 1 --os-type linux --os-variant fedora7 --network bridge=virbr0 --graphics none --noautoconsole --import
```

It starts reaching out to cloud-init and throws warning as,

```
url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [2/120s]: unexpected error ['ConnectionError' object has no attribute 'response']
```

The error is bombarding my console, making it impossible to type anything.

I am sure one of my `virt-install` parameter is wrong, not sure which one!!

Comment: virt-install is meant to _install_ the operating system! There is no point to using it with an already existing OS!

Comment: thanks Mich... `virsh create ` works...

Comment: normal behavior from cloud-init. You can disable the external datasource with a ``dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init`` inside your host (need just to wait couple of minutes for the boot with these errors going).